# Unwanted application starts automatically when I login

Tags: startup

When I log in to my Ubuntu system several applications that I added to startup list (by using System->Preferences->StartUp Application) start automatically.

Last times I am seeing that among those startup applications there is also another one called "Konqueror" (which is a browser and browse me automatically https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4458/bakhtiyor) which starts automatically. But I didn't add this application to startup list. I looked for every place that I knew to see why it was loading automatically but I could not find it.

Could anybody help me to find out how that application is starting up automatically when a session starts please?

**Note** that I don't have root permission in my system, because it is in my working place. I am using Ubuntu Desktop and GNOME.

Thank you.

Comment: Konqueror is KDE - are you using Kubuntu? Or are you using both GNOME/KDE?

Comment: you say you added the application to startup and it autostarts ? That is what it is supposed to do, isn't it? Remove those from startup applications or Did I understand your question wrong ?

Comment: @mathepic. I am using Ubuntu Desktop and GNOME.

Comment: @sagarchalise. But I didn't add Konqueror to startup list. This is the problem.

Comment: is kde set to remember your session?

Comment: @KDE. I use Gnome only. Did you mean this or another thing? Sorry for not understanding you.

Comment: I think autostart sit at $HOME/.config/autostart/. May be you need to change something there.

Comment: @sagarchalise. I have checked that. It has only applications that I had added to startup list. But Konqueror is not there.
I think that @nejode is in a right way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System>Preferences>Startup apps, then on the Options tab uncheck the "Automatically remember...." checkbox.

Comment: It is currently unchecked. But I think you are right. Because I remember that I was checking it some times. But it is unchecked now. Is there any file corresponding to it so that I could find and remove Konqueror from it?

Comment: Close all not wanted startup apps and press the "Remember the current running applications" button on the same tab, but leave the checkbox empty.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks. So, the main factor for this problem was that button called "Remember Currently Running Applications". Somehow I clicked this button not knowing the meaning and at that time Konqueror had been started. The strange thing is that this button even don't ask confirmation. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: See my answer. I found configuration file for that and it is more easier to solve my problem by just removing this configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the main reason for automatically running Konqueror after initiating session was that I pressed accidentally the button called `Remember Currently Running Applications` which is located in `System>Preferences>Startup` apps under the `Option` tab.

**@nejode** had guessed that first and posted his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27869/unwanted-application-starts-automatically-when-i-login/27872#27872). In the comment he wrote that I can close all not wanted apps and press the `Remember Currently Running Applications` button again. I did that and it worked fine.

But, I started to look after the configuration file where this information is stored.  Finally I have found it in `~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session` folder. So removing all files from their will remove all remembered running applications. And I think it is more easier way to do that.

By the way, would be nice in future to see `Undo` button along with `Remember Currently Running Applications` button.

Cheers.