# Abiword starts automatically each restart

Tags: startup, 15.04

Abiword starts automatically each restart, on any user. Already checked out Startup Applications. Remember session is turned off.

([Unwanted application starts automatically when I login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27869/unwanted-application-starts-automatically-when-i-login))

Additional info, may be it'll give a clue - I configured VNC server on this machine to run, so sometimes, in additional to regular Ubuntu/Unity sessions I start XFCE4 session. I think this behavior started after VNC4 configuration, but `~/.vnc/xstartup` does not contain abiword - just regular xfce startup stuff.

What are additional places where I can look?

Comment: I didn't configure VNC, but it started happening for me I believe after installing AbiWord at all. I forget if it happened with Utopic as well as Vivid or with Vivid only. In the meantime I'll go through my filesystem to see what refers to abiword...

Comment: I don't see anything in either /etc or /usr or ~/.* that would lead to this; sorry... the problem must be elsewhere :S Though I'm wondering if it's tracker related, because I see a bunch of tracker crash messages on startup too (sporadically)...

Comment: I also see those messages... Looks like clean install will fix my problems

Comment: Anton you probably don't need to clean install maybe just create a new user and then it might not start. But that would tell you it is in your home folder for the bad configuration.

Comment: This problem recurred for me after the 15.10 upgrade.

Answer (score 18):

This is a bug in AbiWord associated with upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04. Resolved by removing `AbiCollab.service` as follows:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.AbiCollab.service
```

For full discussion about this bug, visit the bug report link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/1432271

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked these folders?

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
~/.config/autostart
```

I had same problem with skylync IM. You can also check package contents and see what files it will install.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry that I can't confirm your solution - I fixed the problem by `sudo apt-get remove abiword`...