# Libreoffice Writer start automatically after login. Ubuntu 15.04, after installing Lubuntu desktop

Tags: libreoffice

after installing Lubuntu-Desktop in a regular Ubuntu 15.04 installation i now have Libreoffice-Writer that starts automatically after login. I remember i found the same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 but i don't remember how to fix that.
What could cause libreoffice-writer to open automatically after login?
Could anyone help?

Comment: It could be possible that _Libre office Writer_ is one of the `startup applications`, in which case open `startup applications` using dash and _unselect_ the _Libre office Writer_ option.

Comment: unluckily it's not such case. i remember the solution was something like removing pidgin or thunderbird and i don't remember why those packages ended up launching libreoffice-writer after login. i am still googling for a solution.

Comment: Did you previously have any option activated, that restores the old session?

Comment: no i didn't, but i solved uninstalling lubuntu

Comment: Maybe it is the same deal as with the Abiword autostart:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/622220/abiword-starts-automatically-each-restart

Comment: you are right xor. uninstalling telepathy fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough

```
sudo apt-get remove telepathy*
```

fixed that strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens but I know how to solve it. Install lxsession-edit

```
sudo apt-get install lxsession-edit
```

run `lxsession-edit`

Uncheck "Chat". Hope it helps :)